# A linking error when building APK files of QML apps

Tags: android, qt, qml, linker-errors, armv7

I use Qt 5.12 on a Windows 7 X64 machine and below is the *Devices* on Qt Creator 4.8:

[image]

As it's shown, SDK, NDK and JDK seem to be fine.

Through this path, I went to create a simple QML project called "test_1":

> File => New File or Project => Application (template) => Qt Quick
>   Application - Empty => The project name (Test_1) => (Build System)
>   qmake => Minimal Required Qt Version 5.12 => Kits (Android X86, Arm7
>   and Desktop) => Finish

And here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello QML World")
}
```

The SDK packages are also as follows:

[image]

Is there something faulty up to here?

Now testing the program using the *kits*:
*Desktop*: **OK**
*Android X86* or *Arm7* : **Faild**

Here's all contents of the *Compile Output* window in the red colour:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>     Android resource linking failed Output: C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:39: error: 'orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density' is incompatible with attribute configChanges (attr) flags [locale=4, fontScale=1073741824, keyboard=16, keyboardHidden=32, layoutDirection=8192, mcc=1, mnc=2, navigation=64, orientation=128, screenLayout=256, screenSize=1024, smallestScreenSize=2048, touchscreen=8, uiMode=512].
>     error: failed processing manifest.
>
> Command: C:\Users\Abbasi.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\83adb1c826b3da76392f22b7ff050e9c\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\ C:\Users\Abbasi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar\ --manifest\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\ -o\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\ -R\ @C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\ --auto-add-overlay\ --java\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\ --custom-package\ org.qtproject.example.Test_1\ -0\ apk\ --no-version-vectors
>   Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
>   Output: C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:39: AAPT: error: 'orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density' is incompatible with attribute configChanges (attr) flags [locale=4, fontScale=1073741824, keyboard=16, keyboardHidden=32, layoutDirection=8192, mcc=1, mnc=2, navigation=64, orientation=128, screenLayout=256, screenSize=1024, smallestScreenSize=2048, touchscreen=8, uiMode=512].
>
> error: failed processing manifest.
>   Command: C:\Users\Abbasi.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\83adb1c826b3da76392f22b7ff050e9c\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\ C:\Users\Abbasi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar\ --manifest\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\ -o\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\ -R\ @C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\ --auto-add-overlay\ --java\ C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Q_Apps\QML_Apps\Test_1\build-Test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\ --custom-package\ org.qtproject.example.Test_1\ -0\ apk\ --no-version-vectors
>   Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s 14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date Building the android package failed! -- For more information, run this command with --verbose. 13:40:16: The process "C:\Qt\5.12.0\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14. Error while building/deploying project Test_1 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (Clang Qt 5.12.0 for Android ARMv7)) When executing step "Build Android APK"

I even went for [android-ndk-r17c-windows-x86_64.zip](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) and replaced it with *NDK r18b*, but no changes in the result!

What is the problem please? Isn't that related to the path I created the project?
I think you, too, create Android apps using the Arm7 kit and building the application is part of its creation. So there must be some way to solve the problem. Agree?
Would you help.

Comment: Is the project created with an old version of Qt?

Comment: As I said, it's Qt Creator 4.8.0. I'm not sure but the last time I could build the app with these specifications the APIes were higher. Isn't the issue related to APIes?

Comment: Which API version works for you?

Comment: For both APIes 27 and 28, it works fine and creates the APK file. I'm going to test more APIes. But a problem which can rise could be that the built *apk* file with high APIs may not work fine with real Android devices! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that even tho the Qt documentation says API 21, it doesn't really work, I get the same manifest errors if I target API 21.

Furthermore, the google market currently doesn't accept apps that target anything lower than API 26. And that is a fast moving target.

This however doesn't mean you must limit yourself to devices that run Android 8 or above. You can specify the lower API limit in your manifest file.

Activate the Android kit for your project, then go to the project settings, in the `Build Steps`, expand the `Build Android APK` pane, set the `Android build SDK` to `andrid-28`. Then further down, there is a button `Create Templates` - click that to generate an editable manifest file. After you click it, it will add an `AndroidManiest.xml` file to your project. Double click that to open it in the manifest editor, then set `Minimum required SDK` to 19, and the target SDK to 28.

This also means that you really only need API 28, it seems that the APIs themselves are "reverse-compatible" with older versions, meaning you don't need API 19 to use it as a minimum required version. As long as you provide a lower minimum version, the app should work just fine even if it targets the latest version.

Comment: Thank you. does it mean that for every QML app to work on Android devices I need to "create a template" again?

Comment: If you don't, Qt will use some "automatic" manifest file, which means that if you want to modify it in any way, you do have to create an editable template. You don't need it for the app to work, you need it so you can customize it.

Comment: +1. Is *Arm7* the best kit to create *apk* files to work on real devices please? I'm used to firstly use it in the *Debug* mode and then *Release*. Afterwards, the *apk* created by *Arm7 Release* will be used on devices. Is it a right way please? And if so, should I "create a template" for the *Release* mode too, apart from *Debug* on *Arm7*?

Comment: The template is for "android" devices, you don't need more than one, even if you target different android architectures and different builds.

Comment: A problem I previously also was stuck into was that when installing the app (a *Pingpong* game) only [part of that](https://imgur.com/a/OYUEytz) would be shown on the real device. The file `main.qml` in my program starts [this way](https://codeshare.io/G8eAZB). Do you think there's a problem with the settings in terms of length, width etc which causes that inconsistency, please?

Comment: Use `Window.FullScreen` visibility on android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed that part of the code to [this](https://codeshare.io/21Xnxq) but still no changes in that case. :(